# How to add the javascript of Google Maps JavaScript API's Place Autocomplete Address Form in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-places-api

How do I add the following into my rails app?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

I tried the following.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "fromliving.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete", async: => true, :defer => true %>
```

I have the `initAutocomplete()` function in a seperate javascript fromliving.js

I get the following errors.

```
syntax error, unexpected => ...ck=initAutocomplete", async: => true, :defer => true );@outp... ... ^ 
Can't assign to true ...tAutocomplete", async: => true, :defer => true );@output_buf... ... ^ 
syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting :: or '[' or '.' ...ete", async: => true, :defer => true );@output_buffer.to_s ... ^
```

This is my initAutocomplete() function.

```
function initAutocomplete() {
// Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
// location types.
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
/** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
(document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
 types: ['geocode']
});

// When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
// fields in the form.
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
   fillInAddress(autocomplete, "");
});

autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
/** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
(document.getElementById('autocomplete2')), {
  types: ['geocode']
});
autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', function() {
fillInAddress(autocomplete2, "2");
});
}
```

I have removed the `API_KEY` here but it's present in the Rails application.

Comment: I know this is not really an answer, but why can't you just use the script tag directly? you can just paste it in the layout as you have at the very top of the question.